# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/_next/webpack-hmr' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established in Next.js with Nginx

Tags: nginx, websocket, next.js, socket.io, safari

I do Web app on NextJS with Socket.IO.

When I run my app, everything is fine. But after 2 minutes errors appear.

NGINX logs:

```
172.19.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2022:16:27:39 +0000] "POST /api/ HTTP/1.1" 200 147 "http://localhost/en" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.6.1 Safari/605.1.15"
172.19.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2022:16:27:59 +0000] "GET /_next/webpack-hmr HTTP/1.1" 101 269 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.6.1 Safari/605.1.15"
...
172.19.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2022:16:29:21 +0000] "GET /_next/webpack-hmr HTTP/1.1" 101 71 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.6.1 Safari/605.1.15"
172.19.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2022:16:29:26 +0000] "GET /_next/webpack-hmr HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.6.1 Safari/605.1.15"
```

101 -- fine. 499 -- errors. But nothing happens, where are the errors coming from?

In console I see this error on each 499:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/_next/webpack-hmr' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established
```

And this problem only on Safari (MacOS)!

On Chrome everything is okay.

Answer (score 11):

From Next.js 12, HMR (Hot Module Replacement) in development uses a WebSocket connection.

When using Nginx with Next.js you'll have to configure it to pass through the WebSocket request properly.

> In some cases when proxying requests to the Next.js dev server, you
> will need to ensure the upgrade request is handled correctly. For
> example, in `nginx` you would need to add the following configuration:
>
> ```
> location /_next/webpack-hmr {
>     proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr;
>     proxy_http_version 1.1;
>     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
>     proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"; 
> }
> ```
>
> — [Next.js, Upgrade Guide, Next.js' HMR connection now uses a WebSocket](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/version-12#hmr-connection-now-uses-a-websocket)

Comment: Thanks, it works. Though instead of creating a new rule, I just added the additional headers to the exiting one. Is there any advangate of having this over the other?

Comment: @jasxir Adding to an existing rule is completely fine.